# Ruby, How to add a param to an URL that you don't know if it has any other param already

Tags: ruby, url, parameters

I have to add a new param to an indeterminate URL, let's say `param=value`.

In case the actual URL has already params like this

```
http://url.com?p1=v1&p2=v2
```

I should transform the URL to this other:

```
http://url.com?p1=v1&p2=v2&param=value
```

But if the URL has not any param yet like this:

```
http://url.com
```

I should transform the URL to this other:

```
http://url.com?param=value
```

I feel worry to solve this with Regex because I'm not sure that looking for the presence of `&` could be enough. I'm thinking that maybe I should transform the URL to an [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) object, and then add the param and transform it to String again.

Looking for any suggestion from someone who has been already in this situation.

#### Update

To help with the participation I'm sharing a basic test suite:

```
require "minitest"
require "minitest/autorun"

def add_param(url, param_name, param_value)
  # the code here
  "not implemented"
end

class AddParamTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_add_param
    assert_equal("http://url.com?param=value", add_param("http://url.com", "param", "value"))
    assert_equal("http://url.com?p1=v1&p2=v2&param=value", add_param("http://url.com?p1=v1&p2=v2", "param", "value"))
    assert_equal("http://url.com?param=value#&tro&lo&lo", add_param("http://url.com#&tro&lo&lo", "param", "value"))
    assert_equal("http://url.com?p1=v1&p2=v2&param=value#&tro&lo&lo", add_param("http://url.com?p1=v1&p2=v2#&tro&lo&lo", "param", "value"))
  end
end
```

Comment: You are on the right track, convert the URL to an URI object and do the needful

Comment: @Anand I'm checking the classes [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html), [URI::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/HTTP.html), [URI::Generic](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html)... and I am not finding the trick.

Comment: once done,please post your answer.

Comment: also checking [Addressable](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/) and also not finding any `add_param` solution.

Comment: Addressable has an even more obvious way of decoding and encoding queries. See [`query_values`](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/Addressable/URI.html#query_values-instance_method) and the associated `query_values=`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI("http://url.com?p1=v1&p2=2")
ar = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query) << ["param","value"]
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(ar)
p uri #=> #<URI::HTTP:0xa0c44c8 URL:http://url.com?p1=v1&p2=2&param=value>

uri = URI("http://url.com")
uri.query = "param=value" if uri.query.nil?
p uri #=> #<URI::HTTP:0xa0eaee8 URL:http://url.com?param=value>
```

***EDIT:(by fguillen, to merge all the good propositions and also to make it compatible with his question test suite.)***

```
require 'uri'

def add_param(url, param_name, param_value)
  uri = URI(url)
  params = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query || "") << [param_name, param_value]
  uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
  uri.to_s
end
```

Comment: yep, the `uri.query == nil` condition checking is the approach I'm playing too, but it looks very ugly :/, looks like the Ruby URL classes are not very friendly.

Comment: checking edge cases.. moment

Comment: no need for conditionals: `URI.decode_www_form(uri.query || "")`.

Comment: @tokland could you update the one you are advicing in my answer?

Comment: I have edited the answer to merge all the good propositions and also to make it compatible with my question test suite.

Comment: @fguillen nice thing I learnt today from your question? :) `uri.to_s` gives back the `url`. I was looking for the same since 30 mins. Where you get it? :)

Comment: I just guessed, the Ruby way :)

Comment: I tried `inspect` but no result, when I saw `to_s`, got surprised.

Comment: @tokland `uri.query || ""` nice idea it is.

Comment: @fguillen, it would probably be better to create your own answer, and refer to Priti's code than to edit someone else's code in their answer. I think you'll find that the majority of people would say that the other people's code is for them to edit, even when they ask. Stack Overflow isn't a forum, it's more like a reference book like Wikipedia. Keeping it apparent where answers come from is important.

Comment: @theTinMan I understand your point, but creating my own answer and not accepting Priti's answer would be unfair for him, and noisy for the _reference book_ experience you have mentioned. I didn't modify the Priti's code but just polish it.

Comment: For Rails applications, use `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query` and `Rack::Utils.build_nested_query` for proper handling of Array parameters.

Answer (score 2):

More elegant solution:

```
url       = 'http://example.com?exiting=0'
params    = {new_param: 1}
uri       = URI.parse url
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form URI.decode_www_form(uri.query || '').concat(params.to_a)
uri.to_s #=> http://example.com?exiting=0&new_param=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you may also not know if this parameter already exists in url. If you want to replace it with new value in this case, you can do this:

```
url = 'http://example.com?exists=0&other=3'
params = {'exists' => 1, "not_exists" => 2}
uri = URI.parse url
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(URI.decode_www_form(uri.query || '').to_h.merge(params))
uri.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use my gem [`iri`](https://github.com/yegor256/iri):

```
Iri.new('http://url.com?p1=v1&p2=v2').add(:param, 'value').to_s
```