# Send selected user data to another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ive created a search bar that allows visitors to search users on my site. When I search for a user (let's say I type "Brittany" into the search bar), Brittany's mini-profile (or profile card) is generated with the following code:

```
<div class="card">

    <div class="columns">

        <div class="col">

  <%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:thumb), :class => 'round-image-125' %>

<br><br>
<font color="#ee4d50" font size="3"><b>Services:</b>

        </div>

          <div class="col">

             <div class="name">
          <%= link_to user.firstname, user %> <%= user.lastname %>

    </div>
        <br>
          <font color="#4d4d4d" font size="3"><b><%= user.city%>, <%= user.stateprov%></font></b>

         <br><br>
         <font color="#2c78d3" font size="4"><b>Bio:</b></font> 

        <br><br>
         <%= user.bio%>

         <br><br>
         <font color="#2c78d3" font size="4"><b>Categories:</b></font>             
</div> 
        </div>
             </div>
```

When a visitor clicks on the searched user's first or last name, I want this same card populated with the user's data to appear on the following page (complete.html.erb).

How would I go about generating a link that passes the searched user's data over to the next page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails will evaluate the ruby in the `.html.erb` file in order to add dynamic content.

You will have to add parameters to the URL that the user clicks. This parameter will have to reference to a record (or set of records) in your database.

I found a helpful article on how to get started on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16623769/5937706